# Stop inserting duplicate rows when loading xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdo

I would appreciate if somebody could help me solve my problem with inserting data from xml file into the database. I want to prevent adding duplicate rows in my database after refreshing the page. Here is my code:

```
public function getAll() {

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load('newXMLDocument.xml');

  $xmldata = $xml->getElementsByTagName('book');
  $xmlcount = $xmldata->length;

  for($i=0; $i< $xmlcount; $i++){

    $author = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('author')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $name = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    try {
      $statement = self::$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `books`( `Author`, `Name`) values( ?, ?) ");
      $statement->bindParam(1, $id);
      $statement->bindParam(2, $author);
      $statement->bindParam(3, $name);

      $statement->execute(array(
        $author,
        $name
      ));


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Downvoted for not properly formatting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your for loop, and before insert data, run query to check if values exists before submitting, then run if statement to prevent running insert query if row exists

```
for loop
$query = 'SELECT `Author`,`Name` from `table` where `Author` = $author AND `Name` = $name';

if($query != null){
   insert new row
}

end for loop
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! I have tried it, but I still keep getting duplicate results. Do you think it might be the columns in my database, maybe I need to set them to be with a UNIQUE key?

Comment: It is better to set a unique key for your database table, but it wont matter in your case, please mark result as correct if it was right to help others =)

Comment: Actually, it worked, only if there are results in the database, but when I delete them and try to load the data from the xml again, it stopped loading them and it is not inserting the data.

Comment: try to use     mysqli_num_rows($query)>0 or     count($query) > 0